# log in into two different applications which are merge in one with one log in details

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using Yii framework, and have one Data Base for my web application, 
and i have one data base for Mibew messenger (webim chat), so I have two different databases.

I have one log in page for administrator page, and chat messenger have it's own log in page, 
what I want to do is when i log in with my administrator details (which are in Yii web app database) to be automatically log in Mibew messenger.

I use this messenger inside my application.

Any suggestion how can I fix this problem,

Sorry if my question confused you, I don't know how to ask it correctly :)

Thank you very much, 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only have one database containing the login details, and connect to that database with the other application just for the login details. Or build a login API for one of the applications to use.